# Limits in span categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

What are the limits in the span categories? and what is known about them in the literature?

Comment: Some quick basics are: in as far as they exist limits are also colimits, and vice versa. If the underlying category $\mathcal{C}$ is extensive then the coproduct/product in $Corr(\mathcal{C})$ is given by disjoint union in $\mathcal{C}$. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span#LimitsAndColimits

Comment: these are bicategories.

A. Carboni, S. Kasangian and R. Street, Bicategories of spans and relations, J. Pure and Appl. Algebra, 33 (1984)

B. J. Day, Limit Spaces and Closed Span Categories, Lecture Notes in Math.,420 (Springer, Berlin-New York, 1974), 65-74.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two interesting classes of limits in bicategories of spans (which, as Urs mentioned, are necessarily also colimits, since $\mathrm{Span}(C)$ is equivalent to its opposite).

The first is a generalization of Urs's comment: any [van Kampen colimit](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/van+Kampen+colimit) in $C$ is a (co)limit in $\mathrm{Span}(C)$ — and conversely, this property characterizes van Kampen colimits.  This is in

- Pawel Sobocinski and Tobias Heindel, *Being Van Kampen is a universal property*, [arXiv:1101.4594](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4594)

The second is that $\mathrm{Span}(C)$ always has [Eilenberg-Moore objects](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Moore+category) for comonads (a sort of 2-categorical limit) — and this figures in a characterization of bicategories of the form $\mathrm{Span}(C)$.  This is in

- Stephen Lack, R.F.C. Walters, and R.J. Wood, *Bicategories of spans as cartesian bicategories*, [TAC 24 (1)](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/24/1/24-01abs.html).

Comment: Dear Prof. Mike Shulman, I write some notes about Gray-tensor of 2-categories and pseudofunctor (time ago you ask her  about a generalization of Gray product to pseudofunctor), My EM is "sergiobuschi@yahoo.com" mine is a little work, but if you want I  traslate (as I can) and send you.

Comment: That's off-topic here, so please email me directly or post a comment at the question in question.