# Limits in Span(Vec)

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let **Vec** be the category of real vector spaces and linear maps.  Let **Span(Vec)** be the bicategory of correspondences between real vector spaces.  I am trying to understand lax limits in **Span(Vec)**.  What kind of diagrams in **Span(Vec)** have lax limits?

A related question is asked below, but I am hoping this case has a clear answer.

[Limits in span categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139216/limits-in-span-categories)